# eval and parse in for loop at the end of a function in R: not creating new variables

Tags: r, function, for-loop, eval

Long story short, I am adding a large number of categorical variables to a data set that would be incredibly monotonous to do any other way that with a function (around 400 new variables). The function I wrote seems a bit bizarre and I am not sure if there is a better way to do this, however, it works and I am proud of it since I wrote it by myself. I am essentially building strings for each variable that look like this "dataset$var.name <- 'something that assigns a 0 or 1'" and then using eval(parse(text = stringvector[i])) in a for loop to run each element of the vector.

However, I noticed that while the function does run when I add the for loop to the end (I know this because the for loop takes awhile to run due to the size of the dataset and the number of variables I am adding), it does not actually add the variables to the dataset. Here is some example code,

```
var1 <- sample(c(0,1), size = 7, replace = TRUE)
var2 <- sample(c(0,1), size = 7, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(cbind(var1, var2))

examplefunct <- function(){
   varnames <- c("var3","var4","var5")
   varstrings <- NULL    

   for(i in 1:length(varnames)){
     varstrings[i] <- paste("df", varnames[i], sep = "$")
   }

   pastenames <- NULL
   for(i in 1:length(varnames)){
      pastenames[i] <- paste("","sample(c(0,1), size = 7, replace = TRUE)", "",sep = "")
      pastenames[i] <- paste(varstrings[i],pastenames[i], sep = " <- ")
   }
   for (i in 1:length(pastenames)){
      eval(parse(text = pastenames[i]))
   }
}
```

Like I said, this does not add the variables to the dataset as I want. To make it work, modify the function to return pastenames, I make it an object, and then run the for loop outside the function like so,

```
var1.1 <- sample(c(0,1), size = 7, replace = TRUE)
var2.1 <- sample(c(0,1), size = 7, replace = TRUE)
df.1 <- data.frame(cbind(var1.1, var2.1))

examplefunct.1 <- function(){
   varnames.1 <- c("var3","var4","var5")
   varstrings.1 <- NULL    

   for(i in 1:length(varnames.1)){
     varstrings.1[i] <- paste("df.1", varnames.1[i], sep = "$")
   }

   pastenames.1 <- NULL
   for(i in 1:length(varnames.1)){
      pastenames.1[i] <- paste("","sample(c(0,1), size = 7, replace = TRUE)", "",sep = "")
      pastenames.1[i] <- paste(varstrings.1[i],pastenames.1[i], sep = " <- ")
   }
   return(pastenames.1)
}
pastenames.1 <- examplefunct.1()
for (i in 1:length(pastenames.1)){
      eval(parse(text = pastenames.1[i]))
}
```

This works fine, however, I would like to know why it does not work inside the function and/or what I am doing wrong. Like I said, I know the way I am going about adding these variables is a bit bizarre, but it does work and I was not quite sure how else to attack this. Also, feel free to correct anything else in my script that seems abnormal or inefficient. I am still learning.

Comment: `eval(parse())` is something a beginner shouldn't be using. It's totally inappropriate and inefficient here. For instance, `setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1,7*3,TRUE),ncol=3)),c("var3","var4","var5"))` is enough to produce the extra columns of your example.

Comment: A few things: a. Don't do `data.frame(cbind(...)))`; sooner or later you'll cause a type error. You just need `data.frame` by itself. b. Sorry to break it to you, but both `for` loops and `eval(parse(...))` are best avoided in R unless you really need them (which is rare). c. I _think_ you're looking for something like `setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 7 * 5, replace = TRUE), 7)), paste0('var', 1:5))`, though that may or may not be similar to the approach you'll need for real data.